# When Should Namespaces Become Their Own, Independent Class Libraries?

Tags: dll, naming-conventions, namespaces

I could use a little advice on naming my assemblies
(ie. When to turn a logical naming convention in my
namepaces into its own DLL).

I recently downloaded an example project with a ton of 
class libraries in it that almost exactly mirrored the 
namespaces.

To date, I have been building one massive class
library - MyProject.DLL - and referencing it in my 
project. This way, I only need one library and can
access all namespaces using it.

But, in the project I downloaded, there seems to
be a DLL for every namespace (and, in some cases,
subcategoreis within a namespaces. For example,
SomeProj.Web.Security has SomeProj.Web.Dll and 
SomeProj.Web.Security.Dll).

I understand that having multiple DLLs can make
it easier to focus on particular areas of the project
(and, probably, updating the DLL withing the site 
easier) but is there a best practice here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this pretty much answers my question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229048.aspx